# How to automate file paths to take mean from a column from multiple csv files?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, mean

I have 600 folders each containing two `.csv` files, of which I want the mean taken from the `LEFT_CHANNEL` and stored in a `data.frame`

here is my code so far:

```
H_results <- read.csv("E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Urban/Nisha/_1/H_results.csv")
mean_H <- mean(H_results$LEFT_CHANNEL)
ndsi_results <- read.csv("E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Urban/Nisha/_1/ndsi_results.csv")
mean_ndsi <- mean(ndsi_results$LEFT_CHANNEL)

data1 <- data.frame(H = mean_H,
                    ndsi = mean_ndsi)

H_results <- read.csv("E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Urban/Nisha/_2/H_results.csv")
mean_H <- mean(H_results$LEFT_CHANNEL)
ndsi_results <- read.csv("E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Urban/Nisha/_2/ndsi_results.csv")
mean_ndsi <- mean(ndsi_results$LEFT_CHANNEL)

new_row <- c(mean_H, mean_ndsi)
data1 <- rbind(data1, new_row)
```

This is working but I want to find a way of automating the file path so that I dont have to copy and paste this and change the folder to `_1, _2, _3` each time.

I'm completely new to R and try to learn so any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following will solve the problem. Untested, since there is no data.

```
H_files <- "E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Urban/Nisha/_%s/H_results.csv"
ndsi_files <- "E:/Audiomoth Files/Winter/Urban/Nisha/_%s/ndsi_results.csv"
col_name <- "LEFT_CHANNEL"
file_nums <- 1:600

data1 <- lapply(file_nums, function(i){
  fl <- sprintf(H_files, i)
  df <- read.csv(fl)
  mean_H <- mean(df[[col_name]])
  fl <- sprintf(ndsi_files, i)
  df <- read.csv(fl)
  mean_ndsi <- mean(df[[col_name]])
  c(mean_H = mean_H, mean_ndsi = mean_ndsi)
})

data1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, data1)
```